# How to reassign a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to reassign a Person pointer in a function called 'nameChanger', what am I doing wrong? how can I reassign a `Person` pointer, to point to another `Person`?

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h> 

typedef struct {
    int age;
    char name[50];
} Person;

void nameChanger(Person ** person);

int main() {
    Person brian;
    brian.age = 27;
    strcpy(brian.name, "brian");

    Person * brian_pointer = &brian;

    nameChanger(&brian_pointer);
    printf("changing name to 'rick' :  %s\n", brian_pointer->name); // should be 'rick'

    return 0;
}

void nameChanger(Person ** person){
    Person rick;
    rick.age = 50;
    strcpy(rick.name, "rick");

    Person * rick_p = &rick;
    *person = &rick;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here, is `rick` is local to the `nameChanger` function. Once the function finshes execution, `rick` will cease to exist. So, the returned pointer and any reference will be invalid.

You can make `rick` a pointer, and allocate memory using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family. In that way, the lifetime of the allocated memory will be until the memory is `free()`-d, so after returning, the access will be valid.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be aware that your local variable `rick` is allocated on the stack frame of function `nameChanger()`, when the function returns, the memory is not valid any more, you should not use that address outside the function.

If you need to do that, use `malloc()` instead, or declare the variable as global variable outside of any function.

Try understand memory layout of a process, especial about stack & function in your case.